# Exact slice size of slice tool

Tags: slices

I'm new to photoshop.  I'm trying to replace an image on a website and I need to slice it to be exactly the 202px wide and 170px high.  The slice also needs to be positioned at exactly 100px from top and 70px from the left relative to another image on the PSD.

Is there a way for me to set up my slice tool/overlay so that it meets exactly those numbers?  Right now, it seems the slice tool can only be controlled by click and drag, and i can't easily tell if it's exactly the dimensions I expect.

Answer (score 1):

To set the exact size and position of a slice in Photoshop:

1. Choose the 'Select Slice Tool' from the Crop/Slice tool group
2. Double click on your slice, the 'Slice Options' window will appear
3. Enter your desired dimensions in the dimensions options at the bottom of the window and click OK.

Note: You can only modify dimensions from the main canvas area, not the 'Save for Web and Devices' dialogue.